# Android, upload photo from gallery to a directory in online server, store in db, retrieve

Tags: java, php, android, mysqli

After 3 days of researching and watching youtube tutorials reading articles, it is not working!
Well I am developing an application for a restaurant, in user profile user can upload a photo, I want to upload this photo to a directory(I am using 000webhost.com) in file manager, then store path in database in a field in Restaurant table named "PicPath"using PHP, and then retrieve it in another activity that is the RestaurantView,
if you may kindly help me
This is the XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2688c1"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/r_image"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/iv_gallery"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_weight="0.02"
            android:layout_below="@+id/r_image"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/r_image" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Update"
        android:id="@+id/btnUpld"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold|italic"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColor="#2688c1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Java code

```
package assaf.alaa.instantmeal;


        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.graphics.Bitmap;
        import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
        import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.provider.MediaStore;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Base64;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.CameraPhoto;
        import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.GalleryPhoto;
        import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageBase64;
        import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageLoader;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.ProtocolException;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.net.URLEncoder;


public class UpdatePhoto extends AppCompatActivity {



    //Refer to views
    ImageView ivGallery,ivImage;
    Button upload;

    Context context=this;
    SharedPreference sharedPreference;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String restName;
    //variables used for camera and photo uploading

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

    Uri selectedImage;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.updatephoto);

        sharedPreference=new SharedPreference();
        restName=sharedPreference.getValue(context);


        ivImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.r_image);

        ivGallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_gallery);

        upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpld);



        ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryPhoto=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (selectedImage == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select a photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) ivImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    new BackgroundWorker(image,restName).execute();
                    Intent intent=new Intent(UpdatePhoto.this, RestProfile.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }


        });

    }//end of onCreate method


    @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // make sure result received from gallery
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && data!=null){

            selectedImage= data.getData();//get the address of the image that has been selected
            ivImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);//display image


        }

         else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),

                    "Something Wrong while loading photo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }//end of onActivityResult method



    class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        Bitmap image;
        String name;

        public BackgroundWorker(Bitmap image, String name) {
            this.image = image;
            this.name = name;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////doInBackground/////////////////////////////////////////////
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // to display loading till content of views are loaded
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UpdatePhoto.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("InstantMeal");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Updating...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        //*****
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);//string representation of the image

            String result = "";
            String uploadphoto_url = "http://alaa-assaf92.comli.com/uploadPhoto.php";

            //////////////////////////////Login As Customer//////////////////////////////////
            try {

                URL url = new URL(uploadphoto_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("restName", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(restName, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("restImage", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(encodedImage, "UTF-8");
                ;
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                String res = buffer.toString();


                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(res);
                result = parentObject.getString("response");

                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return result;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            return result;
        }//end of doInBackGround method


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }//end of post execute

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


    }//end of Background worker class
}//end of class
```

This is the php code:

```
    <?php
     $restName=$_POST["restName"];
     $image=$_POST["restImage"];

     require "connection.php";

     $decodedImage=base64_decode('$image');
     $path="http://alaa-assaf92.comli.com/images/".$restName.".JPG";
     file_put_contents($path, $decodedImage);

    $sql="UPDATE Restaurant
          SET PicPath='$path'
          WHERE RestName='$restName'";
    $check=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     if($check){$result[$response]="Photo Updated Successfully";}
     else{$result[$response]="Process Failed ".mysqli_error($conn);}

die(json_encode($result));


?>
```

Comment: In `PHP`, you're passing an incorrect value to `file_put_contents(....)` you should pass a file path as the first parameter. The path should look something like this: `./images/fileName.jpeg` or `/home/userName/web/images/fileName.jpeg`.

Comment: But the directory will be in the online server with the following domain http://alaa-assaf92.comli.com/

Comment: Yes, but the schema of the first parameter passed to `file_put_contents(...)` should be `file:///` not `http://`.

Comment: <?php
     $restName=$_POST["restName"];
     $image=$_POST["restImage"];

     require "connection.php";

     $decodedImage=base64_decode('$image');
     $path="./images/".$restName.".jpeg";
     file_put_contents($path, $decodedImage);
 
    $sql="UPDATE Restaurant
          SET PicPath='$path'
          WHERE RestName='$restName'";
    $check=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
       if($check){$result["response"]="Photo Updated Successfully";}
       else{$result["response"]="Process Failed ".mysqli_error($conn);}

die(json_encode($result));
      

?>

Comment: it is still not working, it saves the photo in the images folder but when I go to open it from there the photo is there but it doesn't show the photo